# Willena sqlite jdbc cannot open SqlCipher db

Tags: java, sqlite, encryption, sqlcipher

I am trying to figure out how to encrypt a sqlite database in non-android java.

It does not seem to be super straight forward, but I [Willena jdbc crypt](https://github.com/Willena/sqlite-jdbc-crypt) which does seem to be able to create an encrypted database, but I simply cannot figure out how to access a SQLCipher 4 encrypted database with it.

Here is my code.

```
String path = "jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\testServer232.db";
    Connection connection = null;
    try
    {
        // create a database connection
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(path+"?cipher=sqlcipher&key=a");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.setQueryTimeout(30);  // set timeout to 30 sec.

        statement.executeUpdate("drop table if exists person");
        statement.executeUpdate("create table person (id integer, name string)");
        statement.executeUpdate("insert into person values(3, 'leo1')");
        statement.executeUpdate("insert into person values(4, 'yui1')");
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from person");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            // read the result set
            System.out.println("name = " + rs.getString("name"));
            System.out.println("id = " + rs.getInt("id"));
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        // if the error message is "out of memory",
        // it probably means no database file is found
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if(connection != null)
                connection.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            // connection close failed.
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

This code does work, but I don't think that it produces a SqlCipher 4 encrypted database. When I try to open it with DB browser for Sqlite, it does not allow me access when I put the password = a.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I ended up finding the creator of the repository. And he solved it easily and answered really fast.

Here is the solution:
Here are a few things that could be tested:

1. Use version 3.31.1
2. Try to do the database connection using "jdbc:sqlite:file:C:\Users\User1\Desktop\test.db?cipher=sqlcipher&key=password123"as URI (notice the added "file:").
3. Try to add the legacy parameter for SQLCipher as available here (https://github.com/Willena/sqlite-jdbc-crypt#aes-256-bit-cbc---sha1sha256sha512-hmac-sqlcipher). The URI will become something like this: "cipher=sqlcipher&key=password123&legacy=4"

This is now working for me. I recommend that others use it if they are interested in an easy way to do sqlcipher version 4 similarly to how it is done in an android project.